# 'No module named ...' on import

Tags: python, django, import, directory, importerror

I've been trying to follow django tutorials and get started with python for the past few days, but I keep getting stuck at the same point in each one and can't seem to find a solution.

I have a directory that represents a django 'app', in this case called `rango`.

Inside of rango I have a `views.py` file and a `urls.py` file. I also have `__init__.py` in the same folder, so my directory looks like this:

```
rango
  │
  ├── __init__.py
  ├── views.py
  └── urls.py
```

Now when I add:

```
from rango import views
```

to the `urls.py` file I get an error `'No module named rango'`

I read a bunch of other questions and people suggested adding

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

but that didn't change anything. Still getting the same error.

Anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Using python 2.7 on windows

Comment: Please provide a complete stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moe\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Python\tango\tangoproject\rango\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rango import views
ImportError: No module named rango
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: You could try sys.path.append('/path/to/dir/containing/rango')

Comment: still no luck, same error

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a relative import.

In `urls.py`:

```
from . import views
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
__package__ = 'rango'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, using that import I get a different error: 

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

That should at least help clarify what the problem is, right? 

I'm really new to python but I thought the __init__.py file told python that the directory was a package, which makes me confused as to why it's calling the directory a 'non-package'

Comment: Are you trying to `import urls` from a python shell in the same directory ? If so, that error will result.

Comment: I'm importing views from inside the urls file, both views and urls are inside the rango directory.

 The error comes when I try to build urls.py, it throws an error at the from rango import views because it says there's no module named rango